# Как на lua скопировать фал по ftp на веб сервер?

Tags: ftp, lua

У меня есть доступ на фтп веб сервер (хочу на нем сделать автоматическую рассылку), а для этого мне сперва надо со своего компа копировать по фтп небольшой текстовый файл на веб сервер. Как такое копирование реализовать на lua?

Answer (score 0):

Есть такая библиотека - [LuaSocket](http://w3.impa.br/~diego/software/luasocket/ftp.html#put), которая, в том числе, позволяет работать с FTP:

```
local ftp = require("socket.ftp")

local content = "README content" -- содержимое файла
local f, e = ftp.put("ftp://fulano:silva@ftp.example.com/README", content)

if f == nil then
  print(e) -- печать ошибки загрузки файла
end
```